# Cuda/Thrust: remove_if doesn't change device_vector.size()?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a somewhat rather simple cuda question that seems like it should be a straight forward operation: removing elements from 1 array based on the value of a 2nd bool array. The steps I take are:

1. Create a device_vector of bools with the same size as the processed input array.
2. Call kernel which will set some of the elements from (1) to true
3. Call remove_if on input array with predicate using processed array from (2).
4. For each value in the bool array that is set to true, remove the corresponding element from the input array.

What I am seeing is that the input array isn't changed and I am not sure why ?

```
struct EntryWasDeleted
{
    __device__ __host__
    bool operator()(const bool ifDeleted)
    { return true; }
};

    //This array has about 200-300 elements
    //thrust::device_vector<SomeStruct> & arrayToDelete

    thrust::device_vector<bool>* deletedEntries = 
        new thrust::device_vector<bool>(arrayToDelete.size(), false);

    cuDeleteTestEntries<<<grid, block>>>( thrust::raw_pointer_cast(arrayToDelete.data()), countToDelete, heapAccess, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(deletedEntries->data()));

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    thrust::remove_if(arrayToDelete.begin(), arrayToDelete.end(), deletedEntries->begin(), EntryWasDeleted());     

    //I am expecting testEntries to have 0 elements
    thrust::host_vector<SomeStruct> testEntries = arrayToDelete;
    for( int i = 0; i<testEntries.size(); i++)
    { printf( "%d", testEntries[i].someValue); }
```

In this sample, I am always returning true in the predicate for testing. However, when I do: testEntries = deletedEntries and output the members. I can validate that deletedEntries is properly filled in with trues and falses.

My expectation would be that testEntries would have 0 elements. But it doesn't and I get an output as if remove_if didn't do anything. ie: the output is showing ALL elements from the input array. I am not sure why? Is there a specific way to remove elements from a device_vector?

Comment: Have you bothered to read the documentation for remove_if? https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga307d7f64566909172a3f9e16b7e2ad53

Comment: The question posed in your title is different from the question posed in your question (there is a difference between changing the size of a vector, as your title indicates, and changing values contained in the vector.  The two ideas are not the same).  Concerning the question posed in the title, without exception, there is no thrust **algorithm** (like `remove_if`) which modifies *any vector size at all, anywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to capture the iterator that is being returned from remove_if

```
thrust::device_vector<SomeStruct>::iterator endIterator = 
   thrust::remove_if(arrayToDelete.begin(), arrayToDelete.end(), 
deletedEntries->begin(), EntryWasDeleted());
```

Then when you copy data back to the host instead of using thrusts default assignment operator between host and device do this:

```
thrust::host_vector<SomeStruct> testEntries(arrayToDelete.begin(),endIterator);
```

As a side note working with arrays of primitives can often be much more efficient. Like can you store the index of your structs in an array instead and operate on those indexes?